# Correct gradients for word2vec negative sampling skip gram model

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to implement skip-gram word2vec in python using negative sampling.
From my understanding, I should be maximizing the equation (4) from the paper by [Mikolov Et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf).

I have taken the gradients of this equation with respect to Vc, U, and U_rand. Where Vc is the center vector corresponding to the center word, U is the context vector corresponding to a word in the context of the center word and U_rand is the context vector of a randomly sampled word.

I am then calculating the cost function for each combination of word and context word adding them up and printing out the total sum of the whole corpus. I am running this a few times and I do not see an improvement on the whole corpus sum of costs. The cost goes up and then down repeatedly.

I got the following gradients

> grad J with respect to Vc = (1-sigma(V•U))*U - Summation over random
>   vectors (1-sigma(-V•U_rand))*U_rand
>
> grad J with respect to U = (1-sigma(V•U))*V
>
> grad J with respect to U_rand = (1-sigma(-V•U_rand))*-V

So with that being said, I have a few questions:

1. Are these gradients correct?
2. Should I be taking a step in the direction of the gradient? (as opposed to the negative of the gradient) To me, I should be as we are maximizing the cost function
3. for the randomly sampled word are we using its center word representation or context work representation. From the Stanford lecture I watched on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASn7ExxLZws&t=3582s) it seems to be its context vector. But this [source](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/16.pdf) seems to differ.
4. Is adding all the cost function results for the whole corpus a valid way to see improvement? (I do not see why not)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understand your question 2-4. It seems that you don't know what you don't know.

First of all, Skip-Gram (both SG and SGNS) has the following cost function ([derivation of cost function](https://aegis4048.github.io/demystifying_neural_network_in_skip_gram_language_modeling#Derivation-of-Cost-Function)):

[image]

The above equation is for Batch Gradient Descent - one update is made after scanning through the entire corpus of size `T`. This is inefficient because `T` is very large in NLP applications. Therefore, we use [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://aegis4048.github.io/demystifying_neural_network_in_skip_gram_language_modeling#stochastic) (SGD) to update weights for each training sample:

[image]

SGNS uses [sigmoid](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#sigmoid) function to compute binary probability distribution. Equation (4) of mikolove's paper replaces the above cost function: :

[image]

`w` is the input word, and `h` is the hidden layer. `h` is equivalent to the word vector for `w`, because the input layer is one-hot encoded. `c_pos` is the word vector for positive word, and `c_neg` is the word vector for [randomly drawn](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#How-are-negative-samples-drawn?) negative word from the [noise distribution](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#What-is-a-noise-distribution-$P_n(w)$?). `W_neg` denotes for all `K` word vectors for negative words.

A general update equation for any machine learning model is:

[image]

Taking the derivative to the SGNS cost function with respect to theta:

[image]

From this point, we need to calculate gradient with respect to the input weight matrix and output weight matrix:

**Gradient for Input weight matrix**

In both SG and SGNS, only one word vector in the input weight matrix that corresponds to the input word is updated. Since the word vector for the input word is equivalent to the hidden layer, we take the derivative of the cost function `J` with respect to `h`:
[image]

The update equation is then:

[image]

**Gradient for output weight matrix**

Both `c_pos` and `c_neg` are word vectors from the output weight matrix, We take gradient with respect to both of them, separately:

[image]

Here, `σ(c_j⋅h)−t_j` is called the [prediction error](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#pred_error). As the model optimizes the weights, this prediction error will be minimized.

**Do I maximize or minimize?**

The convention in machine learning is to minimize the cost function `J`. But many paper say that they *maximize* the probability of ... bla bla bla. Why is that?

The initial idea of negative sampling is to maximize the probability of observing positive pairs and minimizing the probability of observing negative pairs. Mathematically, it can be translated as:

[image]

`argmax theta` means that we maximize the following probability by adjusting `theta`. In machine learning, it is a common practice to take a natural log to the objective equation to simplify derivations (why take a natural log? read [here](https://aegis4048.github.io/demystifying_neural_network_in_skip_gram_language_modeling#take_natural_log)). Then:

[image]

The authors say that they maximize probability. However, in machine learning, the convention is to minimize the cost function, not to maximize it. To stick to the convention, we add a negative sign to eq (11). This can be done because **minimizing a negative log-likelihood is equivalent to maximizing a positive log-likelihood**. After some mathematical manipulation ([derivation](https://aegis4048.github.io/optimize_computational_efficiency_of_skip-gram_with_negative_sampling#Derivation-of-Cost-Function-in-Negative-Sampling)), we then obtain the cost function we can minimize:

[image]

Comment: in equation 21) why did  sigmoid(-c_neg*h) become sigmoid(c_neg*h) ?